# Vue: Access parent component data in slotted child component?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have two components rad-list and rad-card, I placed a slot element in rad-list where I will place rad-card, now rad-card needs to access a computedResults data from parent rad-list component, how can I access it using vue slots, is it possible?

RAD LIST

```
<template>
<div class="RADlist_maincontainer">
    <layout-pagination-1 v-show="pagination.last_page > 1" :pagination="pagination" @paginate="paginate({ page:pagination.current_page, paginate:paginate })"></layout-pagination-1>
    <div class="RADlist_wrapper">
        <!--rad-card, or any other component which will use computedResults GOES HERE-->
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
    <layout-pagination-1 v-show="pagination.last_page > 1" :pagination="pagination" @paginate="paginate({ page:pagination.current_page, paginate:paginate })"></layout-pagination-1>
</div>
</template>
```

This is how it loks in my template:

```
<rad-list model="Discount" module="Discount" results="discounts">
        <rad-card :item="result" v-for="result in computedResults" :key="result.id" :model="module"></rad-card>
    </rad-list>
```

My full RADlist component justi in case it's needed:

```
<template>
<div class="RADlist_maincontainer">
    <layout-pagination-1 v-show="pagination.last_page > 1" :pagination="pagination" @paginate="paginate({ page:pagination.current_page, paginate:paginate })"></layout-pagination-1>
    <div class="RADlist_wrapper">
        <!--rad-card, or any other component which will use computedResults GOES HERE-->
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
    <layout-pagination-1 v-show="pagination.last_page > 1" :pagination="pagination" @paginate="paginate({ page:pagination.current_page, paginate:paginate })"></layout-pagination-1>
</div>
</template>
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
export default{
name: 'RADlist',


computed:
{
    computedResults: function()
    { 
        return this.$store.state[this.module][this.results];
    },
    pagination: function()
    { 
        return this.$store.state[this.module].pagination;
    },
    ...mapState('Loader', ['loader'])
},


props:
{
    component: { default:'rad-card', type:String },
    module: { default:'Post', type:String },
    action: { default:'list', type:String },
    results: { default:'posts', type:String },
    page: { default:1, type:Number },
    paginate: { default:6, type:Number },

},


mounted()
{
    console.log(this.$options.name+' component successfully mounted');
    this.$store.dispatch(this.module+'/'+this.action, { page: this.page, paginate: this.paginate, loaderId:2473});
},


}
</script>
```

Comment: what functionality do you need inside of computedResults? the name implies it's simply an array of objects

Comment: I added the full rad-list component, but yes, it's an array of objects I get from an API call

Comment: What do you need from computedResults inside the rad-card component?

Comment: well radcard is used to display a card component for each of the objects in my computedResults array of objects

Comment: Ahhh. So you don't actually need to reach into computedResults to do this. Create an `item` prop on rad-card then you can just access the current item in rad-card via that prop. You are already binding the current item to that prop `<rad-card :item="result" ` that's what this is doing. So you are already 1/2 way there. You can read over [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-introduction-to-dynamic-list-rendering-in-vue-js-a70eea3e321/) as well for a more in-depth explanation.